# Merge [search-and-replace] and [find-and-replace]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are:

- [find-and-replace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/find-and-replace) (56 tagged)
- [search-and-replace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/search-and-replace) (17 tagged).

I'd propose to merge them. There's no difference between these two. Then, create a synonym for  [search-and-replace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/search-and-replace) → [find-and-replace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/find-and-replace).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
updating post history, 19 rows affected
updating posts, 18 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 14 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [find-and-replace] and [search-and-replace] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
Tag Synonym search-and-replace -> find-and-replace was approved!
```